# TypeError: Cannot Set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, html

html below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Stopwatch</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><span id="seconds">00</span><span>:</span><span id ="tens">00</span></p>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript below

```
window.onload = function () {
  var seconds = 0
  var tens = 0
  var getTens = document.getElementById('tens')
  var getSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds')
  var start = document.getElementById('Start')
  var stop = document.getElementById('Stop')
  var reset = document.getElementById('Reset')
  var interval
  start.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(interval)
    interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10)
  }

  stop.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }

  reset.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(interval)
    tens = '00'
    seconds = '00'
    getTens.innerHTML = tens
    getSeconds.innerHTML = seconds
  }

  function startTimer() {
    tens++
    if (tens < 9) {
      getSeconds.innerHTML = '0' + tens
    }
    if (tens > 9) {
      getTens.innerHTML = tens
    }
    if (tens > 99) {
      console.log('seconds')
      seconds++
      getSeconds.innerHTML = '0' + seconds
      tens = 0
      getTens.innerHTML = '0' + 0
    }
    if (seconds > 9) {
      getSeconds.innerHTML = seconds
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this (main.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at window.onload) error in console and cannot figure out why. I have tried multiple other solutions including moving the  tag in the HTML as I have seen that helped others however I cannot get it.

Comment: That gives me an ESLint error in atom and still the same error in console. @gurvinder372

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id`s are case sensitive. So you element is `#stop` and not `#Stop`

```
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop')
```

Just make sure to do this for all the elements.

Comment: and the same for `reset` \ `Reset`

Comment: thanks this was it I feel like an idiot. +1 yea I did for all. Cheers

Comment: @Roman yea.. thought it was obvious but yea edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the case of id.
You write `id="start"` in html but `document.getElementById('Start')` in js.